# Validating header and trailer

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I am new to UNIX and I need some help regarding validation of `head` and `tail`. I have a text file named `data.txt` where I have the following data:

```
H,20200701
SK
MK
3
```

Here the header has date and the trailer has the number of rows present in the file.

I need to create a shell script which validates whether the header has the current date and also I need to check whether the trailer has correct count of the number of records.

Comment: Based on your example, I assume that number of records includes the header line?

Comment: Also based on your example, I assume the date format is yyyymmdd.  What sort of validation are you looking for?

Comment: Do you want to test if the date has the correct format or do you want to compare the date against the current date?

Comment: Yes the number of records includes the header line and I need to validate the date with the current date. Thanks !

Comment: Please add your comment to the question so other readers can find the information without going through the comments. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my assumption , this is what you want ?

```
awk -F"," -v dt=$(date +'%Y%m%d') 'FNR==1{ dte=$2; } { l=$0;} 
END { if ( dte==dt && (FNR-1)==l ) print "Yes"; else print "No" } ' data.txt
```

EDIT:

`-F","`   => Set field delimiter as "," comma.

`-v dt=$(date +'%Y%m%d')` => Execute unix command to get current date in the format mentioned in file and stored it in the "dt" variable.

`NR==1{ dte=$2; }`  => If line number is 1 , then store the second field ( date ) from file

`{ l=$0;}`  => Store everyline in variable called "l" . ( so that when last line is passed , it will store the last line of file in "l")

`END { if ( dte==dt && (NR-1)==l )` => In the END Block ( After parsing all lines , check if variable "dte" is equal to "dt" ( output of date command from previous line and date value in file ) and last line "l" matches total number of record (NR) minus 1.If both matches then print yes else No .

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support !

Comment: Pleasure!!! Have a great day !!!

Comment: Can you explain the code if possible ?

Comment: Sure ... I am in travelling ... Please give me some time

Comment: @Lekshmi : Sorry for delay , i have edited the answer with explanation . hope it helps. Still if you need anything pls let me know...

Comment: @StalinVigneshKumar May I recommend that you use `FNR` instead of `NR` in case the OP wants to apply your solution to multiple files in one `awk` call?

Comment: Yeah i thought of that , but then OP needed for one file , so i used NR. But yeah using FNR is always better.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you help! Much Appreciated !